# Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'observe' of null

Tags: javascript, jquery, prototype

I am getting error in this [page console](http://sbdev2.kidsdial.com/colored-marble-micromax-canvas-knight-a350-phone-case.html) : **Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'observe' of null** , I am new to this js concepts.

in google, i found `object is not initialized`, but i am not getting which one.

```
var Aitcg_View_Abstract = Class.create(
{
    id     : '',
    option : null,
    editor : null,
    preview: null,

    templateSyntax: /(^|.|\r|\n)({{(\w+)}})/,
    templateSettings: null,
    scr: null,

    initialize: function( option ) {
        this.option = option;
        this.config = option.config;
        this.id     = this.config.optionId;
        this.editor = option.editor;
        if(typeof(AitPopupHtml)!= 'undefined') {
            Event.observe(document, 'dom:loaded', function(){
                $$('body')[0].insert( {bottom:AitPopupHtml} );
            });
        }
    },

    /**
     * @abstract
     */
    closeEditor: function(){},

    /**
     * Return an array of data necessary to render an editor
     *
     * @return Object
     */
    getTemplateSetting: function() {
        return this.templateSettings;
    },

    /**
     * Init an array of data necessary to render an editor
     */
    _setTemplateSetting: function()
    {
        var c   = this.config,
            t   = this.config.text,
            scr = this.scr,
            options = {
                full_image: c.productImage.fullUrl,
                rand      : c.rand,
                option_id : this.id,

                close_text           : t.close,
                apply_text           : t.apply,
                reset_text           : t.reset,
                cancel_text          : t.cancel,
                save_text            : t.save,
                edit_text            : t.edit,
                required_text        : t.required,
                texttoadd_text       : t.texttoadd,
                addtext_text         : t.addtext,
                pickcolor_text       : t.pickcolor,
                pickcoloroutline_text: t.pickcoloroutline,
                pickcolorshadow_text : t.pickcolorshadow,
                widthoutline_text    : t.widthoutline,
                outline_text         : t.outline,
                shadow_text          : t.shadow,
                shadowalpha_text     : t.shadowalpha,
                shadowoffsetx_text   : t.shadowoffsetx,
                shadowoffsety_text   : t.shadowoffsety,
                addimage_text        : t.addimage,
                addmasks_text        : t.addmasks,
                delmasks_text        : t.delmasks,
                svg_text             : t.svg,
                pdf_text             : t.pdf,
                png_text             : t.png,
                font_text            : t.font,
                fontpreview_text     : t.fontpreview,
                scale_text           : t.scale,
                print_text           : t.print_text,
                print_type_top       : t.print_type_top,
                print_type_bottom    : t.print_type_bottom,
                print_type_bg        : t.print_type_bg,
                print_type_mask      : t.print_type_mask,
                print_type_error     : t.print_type_error,

                masks_title         : t.masks_title,
                predefined_title    : t.predefined_title,
                user_title          : t.user_title,
                text_title          : t.text_title,
                under_template_text : t.under_template_text,
                save_title          : t.save_title,
                save_about          : t.save_about,
                buttonHelp          : t.buttonHelp,

                areaSizeX    : c.area.sizeX,
                areaSizeY    : c.area.sizeY,
                areaOffsetX  : c.area.offsetX,
                areaOffsetY  : c.area.offsetY,

                fontOptions  : c.tools.Text.fontOptions,
                empty_img_url: c.emptyImgUrl
            };

        if (scr) {
            // some window rendering variables for template
            options['img_width']  = scr.curr.width;
            options['img_height'] = scr.curr.height;
            options['width']      = Math.floor(c.area.sizeX * scr.mult) + 'px';
            options['height']     = Math.floor(c.area.sizeY * scr.mult) + 'px';
            options['left']       = Math.max(0, Math.round(c.area.offsetX * scr.mult - 1)) + 'px';
            options['top']        = Math.max(0, Math.round(c.area.offsetY * scr.mult - 1)) + 'px';
        }

        Aitoc_Common_Events.dispatch('aitcg_view_set_template_settings', {view: this, options: options});

        this.templateSettings = options;
    },

    /**
     * Render a bottom control panel of the editor
     *
     * @return string
     */
    _getControlPanelHtml: function()
    {
        if (this.config.editorEnabled) {
            return '<div id="aitcg-control-panel">' +
                '<button class="aitcg-button apply-but" id="submit-editorApply-{{rand}}" >SAVE DESIGN</button>' +
                '<button></button>' +
                '</div>';
        }
        return '';
    },

    /**
     * Init Apply and Reset buttons events
     */
    initObservers: function()
    {
        if (this.config.editorEnabled) {
            $('submit-editorApply-' + this.config.rand).observe('click', this.submitApply.bindAsEventListener(this));
            $('submit-editorReset-' + this.config.rand).observe('click', this.submitReset.bindAsEventListener(this));
        }
    },

    submitApply: function(event)
    {
        Event.stop(event);
        this.option.apply();
    },

    submitReset: function(event)
    {
        Event.stop(event);
        this.option.reset();
    },

    /**
     * Render editor popup header and
     * toolbox if editor in enabled
     *
     * @return string
     */
    _getToolsHtml: function()
    {
        return this.option.tools.render();
    },

    initPreview: function()
    {
        var scale = this.option.calcScale(),
            elementId = this.config.previewContainer,
            container = $(elementId),
            c      = this.config,
            area   = c.area,
            thumb  = c.productImage.thumb;
        this.previewScale = scale;

        var areaParams = {
            width : Math.round(area.sizeX   * scale),
            height: Math.round(area.sizeY   * scale),
            left  : Math.round(area.offsetX * scale),
            top   : Math.round(area.offsetY * scale)
        };

        var html =
                '<div class="aitraph aitraph-bot"></div>' +
                '<img class="aitcg_preview_bg" src="' + thumb.fullUrl + '" />'+
                '<div class="aitraph aitraph-top"></div>' +
                '<div class="aitcg-overlay" style="width:'+ thumb.sizeX +'px;height:'+thumb.sizeY+'px;"></div>';
        container.update(html);

        this._showPreviewBlock( container );

        container.observe('click', this.onPreviewClick.bind(this));

        var title         = c.editorEnabled ? c.text.thumbTooltipEdit : c.text.thumbTooltipPreview,
            viewIconClass = c.editorEnabled ? '' : 'view-icon';
        container.select('.aitcg-overlay')[0]
            .observe('mouseover', function(){Aitcg.tooltip().update(title).show()})
            .observe('mouseout', function(){Aitcg.tooltip().hide()})
            .addClassName(viewIconClass);


        var styleParams = Aitcg.addPxToValue(areaParams);
        $$('#' + elementId + ' .aitraph').each( function(element) {
            element.setStyle(styleParams);
        });

        Aitoc_Common_Events.dispatch('aitcg_option_preview_create_after_' + this.id, {element: container});

        this.preview = new Aitcg_Editor(this.option);
        this.preview.init(container, Aitcg_Editor.MODE_PREVIEW, true, this.previewScale);
        this.preview.load( $('options_' + this.id).getValue() );       
        this.switchToEditor();
         this.startEditor();
       // jQuery( "#aitcg_image_container1" ).trigger( "click" );
    },

    previewReset: function()
    {
        this.preview.reset();
        this.preview.load( $('options_' + this.id).getValue() );
    },

    /**
     * @abstract
     *
     * @param container
     * @private
     */
    _showPreviewBlock: function( container ){},

    /**
     * @abstract
     */
    onPreviewClick: function(){},

    /**
     * Render some template using current view options
     *
     * @param template String
     * @return string.
     */
    renderTemplate: function( template )
    {
        var tempObj = new Template(template, this.templateSyntax),
            options = this.getTemplateSetting();
        return tempObj.evaluate(options)
    },

    _setVYAProductImage: function()
    {
        this._setTemplateSetting();
        this.initPreview();
    }
});
```

please help me to find solution.

Comment: You need to debug your own code. Dumping a large block of code with no indication of where the error is occurring isn't going to work. Narrow it down yourself, and if you still don't understand why the error is happening, ask a question.

Comment: @squint you are absolutely right, i will surely follow your words after some days, but now i am not in that position, Thanks for suggestions....

Comment: This is the perfect time to learn to debug. Were you planning on doing it when your code was working without issue?

Comment: @squint i completely agree..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

At least you are using a wrong selector here:

```
if (this.config.editorEnabled) {
    $('submit-editorApply-' + this.config.rand).observe('click', this.submitApply.bindAsEventListener(this));
    $('submit-editorReset-' + this.config.rand).observe('click', this.submitReset.bindAsEventListener(this));
}
```

should have a `#` character when using jQuery selector by element id, like so:

```
if (this.config.editorEnabled) {
    $('#submit-editorApply-' + this.config.rand).observe('click', this.submitApply.bindAsEventListener(this));
    $('#submit-editorReset-' + this.config.rand).observe('click', this.submitReset.bindAsEventListener(this));
}
```

Also make sure you have objects available everywhere else, where you have an object calling `observe` method, e.g. `Event.observe`, `container.observe` etc. All those `Event`, `container` objects should be defined in your code and have that method.

Comment: That's probably because you also need to do what I proposed in the last paragraph of my answer.